# How to add an adbannerview in UITableViewController in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, adbannerview, gadbannerview

I have a project with a UITableViewController in the storyboard. I want to add an ADBannerView to the bottom of it, does anybody have any idea how to do it? Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drag a iAd Banner View to the footer of your UITableViewController in the storyboard, setup the @IBOutlet and setup the layout constraints.